# Cabal tests on windows 7

Tags: windows, haskell, cabal

I am trying to follow the examples from here http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/#test-suites

When I run cabal test it throws this error `cabal: No test suites enabled. Did you remember to configure with '--enable-tests'?`

so I try `cabal configure --enable-tests` and then `cabal test` but I now get

```
Running 1 test suites...
Test suite test-s3dm: RUNNING...
cabal: permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need to actually build the tests and the program which you want to test. so you need to do `cabal build` after configure.

But I would agree that that error message should be something else.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I am still getting `cabal: permission denied` after it runs the test though...

Comment: yeah, i got that for a while myself. Don't remember what it was, but try deleting the dist folder and try again.

Comment: I Think its trying to delete the test log. Every time i run cabal test its giving me a longer and longer message

Comment: you can increase the verbosity and see what it's trying to do

Comment: `--verbose=3` doesn't give me any more info :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem that you did. The cause of it was that the test suite file wasn't getting compiled into an executable. Turned out that no matter how I configured it, Cabal didn't produce executables for modules located in some namespaces (e.g. `Pkg.Main`) and complained about not being able to find a `Main` module during building phase.

The solution I found was to move both the `Main` module and the `TestSuite` module into the core `src/` folder and to remove the heading `module` declarations in those files.

Here's how my working `cabal` config looks now:

```
name:           Pwn
version:        0.1
cabal-version:  >= 1.2
build-type:     Simple

executable main
  hs-source-dirs:  src
  main-is:         main.hs
  build-depends:   base >= 4 && < 5,
                   random,
                   containers


test-suite test-suite
  hs-source-dirs:  src
  main-is:         test-suite.hs
  build-depends:   
                   base >= 4 && < 5,
                   test-framework >= 0.4.1,
                   test-framework-quickcheck,
                   test-framework-hunit
  type:            exitcode-stdio-1.0
```